# Webpack throwing "Module parse failed" error when using dynamic imports

Tags: reactjs, webpack, importerror

I have a React single page web app that is bundled with Webpack. The app uses dynamic imports to import components from another package that I've created. When viewing in the browser, this error appears:

```
[webpack-dev-server] ERROR in ../../../src/public/index.html 2:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
> <!DOCTYPE html>
| 
| <html lang="en">
```

It's like Webpack is looking in directories above the "src" directory, like "public" (where the index.html file lives), even though I've configured Webpack to only include the "src" directories. The strange part is, if I close the error overlay, the app appears to function as desired. Additionally, commenting out the dynamic import seems to eliminate the error.

Here is my webpack configuration:

```
const include = [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    path.resolve(process.env.APP_DIR, 'src'),
];

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        watchFiles: [`${process.env.APP_DIR}src/**/*`],
    },
    entry: './src/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                include,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            '@babel/preset-react',
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
                include,
                use: [
                  'style-loader',
                  'css-loader',
                  'sass-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                include,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                include,
                use: {
                    loader: '@svgr/webpack',
                    options: {
                        ref: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    output: {
        clean: true,
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
        }),  
        new ProvidePlugin({
            React: 'react',
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'mycomponents': path.resolve(process.env.APP_DIR, 'src'),
        },
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            path.resolve(process.env.APP_DIR, 'node_modules'),
        ],
    },
};
```

and the code doing the importing:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const { default: passedComponent } = await import(`mycomponents/HelloWorld`);
    ...
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

Any help is much appreciated--I've been banging my head on this one for a few days now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I may need a nap. While walking through the issue with my daughter, I realized that I somehow managed to paste a copy of my public directory in my src directory. I had a hunch it was copy pasta. Apologies to anyone who wasted their time reading this post haha